# Is python3's BufferedProtocol an abstraction over TCP? Or is it so low-level that I have to implement the TCP things too?

Tags: python-3.x, tcp, stream, python-asyncio

I am referring to this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.BufferedProtocol

I haven't seen the answer to this question documented anywhere and I want to know the answer in advance of writing any code.

It seems to imply that it is a modification of `asyncio.Protocol` (for TCP) but seeing as though TCP is not mentioned for BufferedProtocol it's got me concerned that I'd have to contend with out of order packets etc.

Many thanks!

Comment: 'Streaming' = TCP.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I can confirm - BufferedProtocol is for TCP only. Not for files or anything else. And it gives you a handle on a zero copy buffer to work with. That's basically all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedProtocol` isn't a protocol based on TCP, it's an *interface* (base class) for custom implementation of [asyncio protocols](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html), specifically those that try to minimize the amount of copying. The [docstring](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/493bf1cc316b0b5bd90779ecd1132878c881669e/Lib/asyncio/protocols.py#L109) provides more details:

> The idea of `BufferedProtocol` is that it allows to manually allocate and control the receive buffer.  Event loops can then use the buffer provided by the protocol to avoid unnecessary data copies.  This can result in noticeable performance improvement for protocols that receive big amounts of data.  Sophisticated protocols can allocate the buffer only once at creation time.

Currently none of the protocols shipped with asyncio derive from `BufferedProtocol`, so the use case for this is user code that needs to achieve high throughput - see the [BPO issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue32251) and the linked [mailing list post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/async-sig/2017-December/000423.html) for details.

> seeing as though TCP is not mentioned for `BufferedProtocol` it's got me concerned that I'd have to contend with out of order packets etc.

Unless you are writing custom low-level asyncio code, you shouldn't care about `BufferedProtocol` at all. Regular asyncio TCP code calls functions such as [`open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) or [`start_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server), both of which handle provide a streaming abstraction on top of TCP sockets in the usual way (using a buffer, handling errors, etc.).

Comment: I am indeed writing custom, low-level asyncio code and it fits my usecase perfectly - there's literally no alternative in the python ecosystem to do it better. I just wanted reassurance before going down the rabbit hole that it wasn't *that* low level so as to require messing about with TCP level stuff... that would be too much!

Comment: @user3188324 I honestly don't understand how `BufferedProtocol` can be an *abstraction over TCP*, as your answer claims. Based on the docs and the issue that spawned it, it seems concerned with efficient throughput and completely orthogonal to TCP. But if it helps with your use case, that's great, and good luck.

Comment: well it's one or the other isn't it. Either TCP is below it or above it in the stack. I didn't want to waste any time finding out the hard way.

Comment: @user3188324 `BufferedProtocol` has nothing to do with TCP whatsoever, it's a helper class for asyncio protocols that require high-throughput data streaming, be it from a pipe, TCP, UDP, regular file...

Comment: It doesn't work for UDP or files only TCP but docs don't mention TCP... but I can confirm that yes it is for TCP